# Is it valid for an HTTP URL query argument to contain a single value without any value name?

Tags: http, url, rest

I have inherited the following URL template from our old RESTful (supposedly) service:

```
http://{host}:{port}/{handle}?{extraQualifier}
```

For instance:

- host=localhost
- port=8182
- handle=abc
- extraQualifier=yabaDabaDoo

Yields the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8182/abc?yabaDabaDoo
```

Is such URL template valid with respect to the http URL specification? I failed to find the definitive answer browsing through various RFCs, but I could miss something important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) section 3.3 HTTP this is perfectly valid. There aren't any specific restrictions for `<path>` (`{handle}` in your case).

From RFC:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
```

**Edit**

Within [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) this is defined in section 3.2.2:

```
http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

Comment: True, but you're citing a really really ancient spec.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the query string is unspecified in HTTP. Although encoded form contents are a very common usage, it's not the only usage. The contents of the query string is entirely up to the server-side code to interpret.